# How are join operators unnecessary in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I've periodically seen it written that joins are unnecessary in LINQ to SQL. Most recently, I saw this statement in one of Joseph Albahari's [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) samples (Chapter 9 - LINQ Operators > Filtering > Joining > Simple Join).

The comment says:

```
// Note: before delving into this section, make sure you've read the preceding two
// sections: Select and SelectMany. The Join operators are actually unnecessary
// in LINQ to SQL, and the equivalent of SQL inner and outer joins is most easily
// achieved in LINQ to SQL using Select/SelectMany and subqueries!
```

I've gone through the Select and SelectMany sections in LINQPad and I definitely want to be doing this the easy way, but my attempts to completely remove joins (and get the same results) have failed.

Anyway, below is the 100% working query I'm trying this out on (full schema pictured below).

```
(from workOrder in dbContext.WorkOrders.Where(wo => wo.WoId == workOrderLine.WoId)
     join projectsBillingSchedule in dbContext.ProjectsBillingSchedules
        on workOrder.ProjectId equals projectsBillingSchedule.ProjectId
     join partyPricing in dbContext.PARTY_PRICING.Where(pp => pp.END_DATE_ACTIVE == endDateActive)
        on projectsBillingSchedule.BillingSchId equals partyPricing.BILLING_SCH_ID
     join measuresPartyRetrofitCode in dbContext.MeasuresPartyRetrofitCodes
        on partyPricing.PARTY_RETROFIT_CODE_ID equals measuresPartyRetrofitCode.PartyRetrofitCodeId
     join measure in dbContext.Measures on measuresPartyRetrofitCode.ConvId equals measure.ConvId
 select measure).FirstOrDefault(m => m.ConvId == workOrderLine.ConvId)
```

---

Please note, certain entities are omitted from the code because they are not strictly necessary for the query to run properly. Aside from that, you can see the joins are done in order of the relationships in the schema image, i.e., from WORK_ORDERS to MEASURES (start by moving away from WORK_ORDER_LINES):
[image]

---

I have tried some using navigation properties, but I run into 2 problems:

1. The SQL outputs in multiple statements (N+1 problem?), and
2. I can't seem to get it all in one statement.

So, back to my question - using the example above (or something else with a lot of joins), how are join operators unnecessary in LINQ to SQL?

**UPDATE**

Ok, I think I've figured out one solution, but this actually requires more lines of code to achieve the same result.

Since that is the case, I'm not sure why it is worth exclaiming that join operators are unnecessary. I'll leave this question open for a while to see if someone wants to make a compelling case against joins.

```
(from workOrder in dbContext.WorkOrders.Where(wo => wo.WoId == workOrderLine.WoId)
 from projectsBillingSchedule in dbContext.ProjectsBillingSchedules
    where workOrder.ProjectId == projectsBillingSchedule.ProjectId
 from partyPricing in dbContext.PARTY_PRICING.Where(pp => pp.END_DATE_ACTIVE == endDateActive)
    where projectsBillingSchedule.BillingSchId == partyPricing.BILLING_SCH_ID
 from measuresPartyRetrofitCode in dbContext.MeasuresPartyRetrofitCodes
    where partyPricing.PARTY_RETROFIT_CODE_ID == measuresPartyRetrofitCode.PartyRetrofitCodeId
 from measure in dbContext.Measures
    where measure.ConvId == measuresPartyRetrofitCode.ConvId
 select measure).FirstOrDefault(m => m.ConvId == workOrderLine.ConvId)
```

Comment: The only compelling case against joins would come from profiling your queries and seeing if there is a performance issue or not.

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about linq-to-sql rather than linq-to-entities? (are you using l2s or entity framework?)

Comment: @Erik I'm using linq-to-entities in my project (where the code is from), but I didn't see a difference in the syntax used in LINQPad in the linq to sql samples - didn't want to confuse the issue. Albahari's comment specifically refers to LINQ to SQL though